# External Services - OpenAPI definition

Tags: external-services

Good Morning,
I am using Salesforce Enhanced External Services and have hit an issue with how Salesforce is interpreting the OpenAPI (Swagger File)

One of the parameters in the swagger file is a field called "time" which is a string representing a time. When i import the definition and Salesforce creates the appropriate actions and apex defined variable it renames the field from "time" to "z0time" and in turn i obviously get an error from the API due to an incorrect fieldname.

Has anyone else experienced this and have any suggestions on how i can get SF not to rename the field. Thanks

Comment: This is a bug in External Services, please report it to Salesforce via a case.

Comment: Thanks i do have a case open with them as well so will see what they say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salesforce is altering the name because Time is a "reserved identifier". You will necessarily need to change the API to not use the literal field value "time" in order for Apex to support this API.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox this is an external system so to get it to work i need to ask the external vendors to potentially change their API is that correct?

Comment: I have just checked this link and i cant see Time as a reserved word. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_reserved_words.htm is there any other location i can look to see where these reserved identifiers are?

Comment: @AndrewC That's the list--it's a bug in the documentation. I reported this to the documentation team.

Comment: This should now be resolved in Summer '20.